# LINQ GroupBy into a new object

Tags: c#, linq

We are working on some LINQ stuff and are new to using the GroupBy extension.

I am editing this post to include my actual code as I tried to use some simple example but it seems that it making it more confusing for those trying to help. Sorry for that.

NOTE We need to sum the Amount field below. We did not attempt that yet as we are just trying to figure out how to extract the list from the groupBy.

Here is my code:

```
myCSTotal2.AddRange(userTotals.Where(w => w.priceinfoId == priceinfoID).GroupBy(g => g.termLength, o => new Model.MyCSTotal2
                            {
                                PriceinfoID = o.priceinfoId,
                                BillcodeID = o.billcodeid,
                                JobTypeID = o.jobtypeID,
                                SaleTypeID = o.saletypeID,
                                RegratesID = o.regratesID,
                                NatAccPerc = o.natAcctPerc,
                                NatIgnInCommCalc = o.natIgnInCommCalc,
                                TermLength = (int)o.termLength,
                                Amount = o.RMR1YrTotal / 12,
                                RuleEvaluation = 0
                            }).Select(grp => grp.ToList()));
```

The error we get when trying to do this is:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 
>   `IEnumerable<List<MyCSTotal2>>` to `IEnumerable<MyCSTotal2>`

EDIT: Thanks for the help. Here is what we ended up with:

```
myCSTotal2.AddRange(userTotals.Where(w => w.priceinfoId == priceinfoID)
                                .GroupBy(g => g.termLength)
                                .SelectMany(cl => cl.Select( o => new Model.MyCSTotal2
                            {
                                PriceinfoID = o.priceinfoId,
                                BillcodeID = o.billcodeid,
                                JobTypeID = o.jobtypeID,
                                SaleTypeID = o.saletypeID,
                                RegratesID = o.regratesID,
                                NatAccPerc = o.natAcctPerc,
                                NatIgnInCommCalc = o.natIgnInCommCalc,
                                TermLength = (int)o.termLength,
                                Amount = cl.Sum(m=>m.RMR1YrTotal / 12),
                                RuleEvaluation = 0
                            })));
```

Comment: Does `PeoplePlus` inherit from `People`?

Comment: But what is the point of group if you need to flatten the list later?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Hi...I was just trying to make an easy example to avoid the complexity of the actual objects we are using. In what we are really doing our objects have 15 fields and we are doing sums/averages etc.

Comment: What are "Enumerated list" and "GenericList", and how do they differ? Which part of all that code "seems to return an GenericList"? Why aren't you certain what it's returning? What does it mean for a result to expect something?

Comment: @melegant, but you are not using the groups to apply aggregation functions, could you be more specific what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: *"we are getting an error"* -- please share with us the full text of the error.

Comment: @melegant, what you are looking is `SelectMany` ext. method:`SelectMany(grp => grp.ToList())`

Comment: A GroupBy creates a two dimensional object <key, List<object>>.  Your AddRange()  expects an one dimension list List<People>.

Comment: @melegant Thanks for the update. When you pasted in the error message, it was full of angle brackets, which caused browswers to swallow most of the error message text. You have to put backticks around generics when you put them in regular text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to flatten the groups you need to use `SelectMany` extension method:

```
SelectMany(grp => grp.ToList())
```

But if that is your current query you don't need to group, you need to project your collection using `Select`:

```
myCSTotal2.AddRange(userTotals.Where(w => w.priceinfoId == priceinfoID)
                              .Select( o => new Model.MyCSTotal2
                               {
                                PriceinfoID = o.priceinfoId,
                                BillcodeID = o.billcodeid,
                                JobTypeID = o.jobtypeID,
                                SaleTypeID = o.saletypeID,
                                RegratesID = o.regratesID,
                                NatAccPerc = o.natAcctPerc,
                                NatIgnInCommCalc = o.natIgnInCommCalc,
                                TermLength = (int)o.termLength,
                                Amount = o.RMR1YrTotal / 12,
                                RuleEvaluation = 0
                              });
```

Comment: Thanks folks. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason in using GroupBy as there are no aggregation functions involved. If you want to have Persons distinct by termLength. Write a DistinctBy. You will get the desired collection this way

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
        (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
            if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then use the extension like this

```
var collection = userTotals
    .Where(w => w.priceinfoId == priceinfoID)
    .DistinctBy(g => g.termLength)
    .Select(o => new Model.MyCSTotal2
        {
            PriceinfoID = o.priceinfoId,
            BillcodeID = o.billcodeid,
            JobTypeID = o.jobtypeID,
            SaleTypeID = o.saletypeID,
            RegratesID = o.regratesID,
            NatAccPerc = o.natAcctPerc,
            NatIgnInCommCalc = o.natIgnInCommCalc,
            TermLength = (int)o.termLength,
            Amount = o.RMR1YrTotal / 12,
            RuleEvaluation = 0
        });
```

Comment: You are correct. We actually though need to sum the 'Amount' field. I did not add that in the code yet as we were just trying to get past the issue of extracting the list we need from the groupBy. I will edit my post. (though the distinctBy is useful for us in another area).

Comment: @melegant, thing is, that you are passing a "list of lists" into the AddRange method. From each group you will receive a list of persons and then you will select that very list, resulting in a list of lists of persons. As octavioccl wrote you, use SelectMany instead. It will aggregate "list of lists" into one single "list" see more here https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful and now I can use that distinct extension for another case we are facing.